# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ","

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

This procedure is getting following error.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SAMPLE
IS
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
    'CREATE TABLE COLUMN_NAMES AS (
     SELECT LISTAGG(COLUMN_NAME, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME) AS STUDENTS
     FROM   
         (SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN_NAME
          FROM BW_COLUMN_ROW_CELL_JOIN)
     )';
END;
/
```

gives:

```
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "," when expecting one of the following:     
* & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem return    
returning <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or   
like like2 like4 likec between into using || multiset bulk    member submultiset
```

Can any one say what is wrong in this?

Thanks.

Comment: @Dazzal. Thank you for your response... Actually, I think Execute Immediate should be used in stored procedure when we want to execute DDL commands which they run at the run time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way (in Oracle 10g and later) is to use the alternative string literal notation - this means you don't need to worry about correctly escaping all the single quotes in the string, e.g. `q'{my string's got embedded quotes}'`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SAMPLE
IS
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE q'[
     CREATE TABLE COLUMN_NAMES AS (
     SELECT LISTAGG(COLUMN_NAME, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME) AS STUDENTS
     FROM   
         (SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN_NAME
          FROM BW_COLUMN_ROW_CELL_JOIN)
     )]';
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem I think is you have single quotes within single quotes. I cant test this at the moment, but I'd suggest you try the following (note the inner quotes are double quotes `''`, which escapes them:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SAMPLE 
IS
BEGIN 
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE COLUMN_NAMES AS ( SELECT LISTAGG(COLUMN_NAME, '','') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME) AS STUDENTS FROM (SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN_NAME FROM BW_COLUMN_ROW_CELL_JOIN) )'; 
END; 
/
```

I'd also try the `create table` part of the code standalone first just to make sure its valid before wrapping it in a proc.

Comment: Wow, its working now... I just added double quotes at the comma... and its done... Thank you so much

Answer (score -1):

You can't use `single quotes` directly in `select statement` of `Execute Immediate` it need to be coded using `CHR(39)`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SAMPLE
IS
BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
     'CREATE TABLE COLUMN_NAMES AS (
             SELECT LISTAGG(COLUMN_NAME,'||chr(39)||','||chr(39)||') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME) AS STUDENTS
             FROM   
            (SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN_NAME FROM BW_COLUMN_ROW_CELL_JOIN))';
END;
```

Comment: execute immediate will execute any valid sql statement which is in string format , in such cases if you specify something like 
`execute immediate 'select 'error' from dual';`
It will give an run time error i.e

`PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "ERROR" when expecting one of the following:

   * & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem return
`

Comment: so to use the single codes in the SQL statement of execute immediate we will use chr(39) !!

If i am wrong tell me the alternative of this

Comment: You can use doubled single quotes to get one "real" single quote into the result string.  In other words `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT ' || CHR(39) || 'quoted literal' || CHR(39) || ' FROM DUAL'` and `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT ''quoted literal'' FROM DUAL'` are equivalent, and IMO the latter is easier to read (and type!).

Comment: The same thing when i have tried like `DECLARE V_STR VARCHAR(40); BEGIN EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT LISTAGG(ename,",") within group (order by deptno) from emp' into v_str; dbms_output.put_line(v_str); END;` But it is giving me error message like `ORA-00904: ",": invalid identifier` 

and i am using `ORACLE11g`